# Assign values to array in another object using setter

Tags: java, arrays, oop

```
protected void Method() {
    ...
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
         int data = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());   
         person[a] = new Person();
         person[a].setID(data);
         person[a].setResults(data);
         a++;
    }
```

}

In another class file

```
protected void Person() {
    int results[] = new int[5];
     ...
    //getters&setters
    public void setResults(int[] results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

The setResults is passing in one value at a time, but the setter is expecting an array, what is a better approach to populate the array in student using setters that only take in one value at a time?

Comment: as I understand from your example : `person.result` always will contain one value `int data = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());` So you can pass to setter `new int[] {data}` .

Comment: Is `Person` supposed to be a class?

Comment: Yes, Person is a class that I have created an array of.

Comment: Are you asking how you would rewrite the `Person` class so that the setter for the `results` array takes only a single `int` value rather than an array of `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a list for this purpose. But for now, you can use a variable to keep store the index at which the value is inserted in the results array and increment it after each insertion.

```
protected void Person() {
    int results[] = new int[5];
    int index = 0; // index to insert at
     ...
    //getters&setters
    public void setResults(int result) {
        if(index < 5) {
            this.results[index] = result;
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call `setResults` like

```
int data = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
person[a].setResults(data);
```

Comment: You need to check `if(index <5)`

Comment: Ok this worked, thanks, there I one more problem I ran into, for every one token read it is assigned to the ID and 1st index in result then it does it again for the next tokenized value, the rest of the indexes in each person object are left empty.